# Solution to integrate car audio with iPod/IPhone at CD quality and optional bluetooth car kit functionally

Tags: audio

I am looking for a solution that would integrate default car audio system with an Apple iPhone, providing this functionality:

- play music/playlists from iPhone at CD quality (no BT for FM)
- charge iPhone
- use car wheel controls to control the play
- read track information on car display
- BT handsfree (AD2P) functionality that stops the music
- answer/reject/suspend/resume call using wheel controls
- to work on Peugeot (2004)
- (optional) Multiple BT connections, be able to pair it with more than one Phone (Multipoint)

Recommend a solution only if you or a fried used it and it was satistfied.

Note, I am aware that at least one product Xcarlink is supposed to do most of these, except the BT Multipoint feature which was confirmed as not supported by them. Still, if you have one please give your review.

Also it would be nice to provide a price range.

Answer (score 2):

As I was almost ready to order Xcarlink because it seems to be the product with the best integration I stopped because I discovered these two issues:

- The Bluetooth module is connected directly to the interface and so audio can only be heard from a call if the radio is in CD changer/AUX mode. So, if you are listening to the radio, you'll miss the call, if you are using Navigation on your phone and switch to the radio, you hear only the radio.
- No BT Multipoint - The Bluetooth module cannot keep connections with more than one device. So if you have several Phones you'll be able to take calls only from one.

Feel free to edit this response!